# Is it undefined behavior to deallocate a pointer returned by a global replacement operator new, without calling a replacement operator delete? (C++17)

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, undefined-behavior, delete-operator

It is considered undefined behavior to invoke SL `operator delete` on a non-null pointer that was not returned by the SL `operator new`, as described here for (1) and (2):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

> The behavior of the standard library implementation of this function is undefined unless ptr is a null pointer or is a pointer previously obtained from the standard library implementation of `operator new(size_t)` or `operator new(size_t, std::nothrow_t)`.

It is therefore also undefined behavior to mix usages of `operator new`, `operator delete` and `operator new[]`, `operator delete[]`. I can't find anything in the standard stating if this also holds for replacement `operator new` and `operator delete` that invoke a user's allocation method. As an example:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t p_size)
{
    void *ptr = UserImplementedAlloc(p_size);
    return ptr;
}

void* operator new[](std::size_t p_size)
{
    void *ptr = UserImplementedAlloc(p_size);
    return ptr;
}

void operator delete(void* p_ptr)
{
    UserImplementedFree(p_ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* p_ptr)
{
    UserImplementedFree(p_ptr);
}
```

Would the following be undefined? Assuming `UserImplementedAlloc` always returns a correct address and never a `nullptr`.

```
struct Simple
{
    explicit Simple(); //Allocates m_bytes
    ~Simple(); //Frees m_bytes
    char * m_bytes;    
};

/*Placement new is not replaced or overridden for these examples.*/

//Example A
{
    //Allocates and invokes constructor
    Simple* a = new Simple();
    //Invokes destructor
    a->~Simple();
    //Deallocates
    UserImplementedFree(static_cast<void*>(a));
}

//Example B
{
    //Allocates
    void* addr = UserImplementedAlloc(sizeof(Simple));
    //Invokes constructor
    Simple* b = new (addr) Simple();
    //Invokes destructor and deallocates
    delete b;
}
```

I'm not looking for lectures about if this is bad practice, I am simply trying to determine if this is defined behavior or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both examples are undefined behavior. Now that I've taken the time to look through the [C++17 standard final draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf), I've found the evidence I need.

---

### Example A

With regards to `operator new`:

*Allocation functions* - § 6.7.4.1.2

> *If the request succeeds, the value returned shall be a
>   non-null pointer value (7.11) p0 different from any previously returned value p1, unless that value p1 was
>   subsequently passed to an `operator delete`*

In example A we call a *new-expression*, `Simple* a = new Simple()`, which internally will call the appropriate `operator new`. We bypass `operator delete` when we call `UserImplementedFree(static_cast<void*>(a))`. Even though `operator delete` would invoke this function, and presumably do the same deallocation, the catch is that any subsequent calls to `operator new` can now potentially return a pointer that matches the address that `a` had. And `a` was never passed to `operator delete`. So we've broken the rule stated above.

---

### Example B

*delete-expression* - § 8.3.5.2

> *...the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer
>   value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (4.5)
>   representing a base class of such an object (Clause 13). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second
>   alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer
>   value that resulted from a previous array new-expression.
>   83 If not, the behavior is undefined.*

In example B, we do not allocate `addr` through a *new-expression*. And then we attempt to use a *delete-expression* to deallocate it. Which violates the rule above.

---

### What would defined behavior look like?

The main feature of these examples is the separation of construction from allocation, and separation of destruction from deallocation. The standard states the following:

*new-expression* - § 8.3.4.11

> For arrays of `char`, `unsigned char`,
>   and `std::byte`, the difference between the result of the *new-expression* and the address returned by the
>   allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental alignment requirement (6.11) of
>   any object type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created. [ Note: Because allocation
>   functions are assumed to return pointers to storage that is appropriately aligned for objects of any type with
>   fundamental alignment, **this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating
>   character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed**. — end note ]

So defined behavior could potentially look like this:

```
{
    //Allocates bytes
    char* bytes = new char[sizeof(Simple)];
    //Invokes constructor
    Simple* a = new ((void *)bytes) Simple();
    //Invokes destructor
    a->~Simple();
    //Deallocates
    delete[] bytes;
}
```

Once again, not necessarily good practice, but defined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler's version of delete might know something, hidden in the implementation, about the deleted pointer that relies on the type.

First calling the destructor manually and then deleting a void* (because otherwise you would call the destructor twice) is not safe. You are not deleting the same pointer in C++ semantics.  It  is the same address at the assembly level and it might free the same amount of memory - or, do you really know that?  You have fooled the compiler to delete a void* instead of the actual type.

Comment: >First calling the destructor manually and then deleting a void*

-- There's no deletion of a void* in the example. UserImplementedFree deallocates the void*, but there's no delete expression or call to the destructor

Comment: And how do you deallocate it then?

Comment: Assume we allocate a large chunk of memory (through malloc, for example) when the program starts and then UserImplementedAlloc and UserImplementedFree tap into an application-level allocator that manages that chunk of memory. There's only ever one true allocation, the rest are application-level allocations.

Comment: In your example you don't do that. You allocate with new.

Comment: If you look above at the replacement definitions of operator new, it allocates through UserImplementedAlloc, It's not the standard library implementation.